# python, stop variable reassignment in every function call?

Tags: python

Assuming:

```
def myfunc(x):
    listv  = []
    listv.append(x)
```

is there a keyword to stop a variable (listv) from being reassigned?
Let's suppose that `NRA` is a keyword:

```
def myfunc(x):
    NRA listv  = []
    listv.append(x)
```

...line will be read and not reassigned but the variable still active appending new values for every function call. I know about the GLOBAL variable, but I just want to know is the keyword exists!

Comment: Check your indentation

Comment: Are you asking for what would be a constant deceleration in another language? If so no there is no way to do so in python.

Comment: As you see in the answer below, the indentation changes the scope of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in functions are not supposed to be persistent between function calls. Because functions are meant to be reusable codes that can be called from different context in the program. So to your answer, NO! There's no keyword for making a variable declared in function persistent.